# Счетчик в jinjja2

Tags: python, jinja2

Не работает счетчик i. Данные заполняются, но переменная не инкрементируется. Значение счетчика i всегда 1. Как поправить?

```
{% set i = 0 %}
{% for class in classes %}
        <li class="group">{{ class }}</li>
        {% set i = i+1 %}
             <li>{{ i }}</li>
              {% if i == 4 %}
                 <br>
               {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Вам случайно не `{{ loop.index }}` и `{% if loop.index == 4 %}` нужны?

Answer (score 4):

Внутри циклов можно использовать `{{ loop.index }}`:

```
{% for class in classes %}
    <li class="group">{{ class }}</li>
    <li>{{ loop.index }}</li>
    {% if loop.index == 4 %}
    <br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**PS.** странно, у меня `{% set %}` тоже не работает, возможно эта бага: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/659

Comment: Но всё же это не объясняет, почему счётчик не работает-то. И да, он считается с единицы, поэтому `+ 1` не нужен

Comment: точно, привычка к индексу добавлять 1 :)

Comment: А у `{% set %}` возможно просто есть своё пространство имён (но изучать соответствующую матчасть мне лень)

Answer (score 2):

Решение этой проблемы описано в документации:

```
{% set ns = namespace(counter=false) %}
{% for class in classes %}
    <li class="group">{{ class }}</li>
    {% set ns.counter = ns.counter+1 %}
    <li>{{ ns.counter }}</li>
    {% if ns.counter == 4 %}
        <br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

> As of version 2.10 more complex use cases can be handled using namespace objects which allow propagating of changes across scopes
>
> Note hat the obj.attr notation in the set tag is only allowed for
>   namespace objects; attempting to assign an attribute on any other
>   object will raise an exception.
>
> New in version 2.10: Added support for namespace objects

Документация: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/  CTRL+F -> `Scoping Behavior`.